# aws: boto3 get all instances of a load balancers

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, elastic-load-balancer

I can able to get the load balancers using below

```
import boto3
elb = boto3.client('elbv2')
lbs = elb.describe_load_balancers()
```

How to get the instances of the `lbs`.

Also How Can I fetch the load balancers which state is not active as describe_load_balanacers only give state `active` load balanceres.

Comment: What do you mean by "instances of the LBs"? Do you mean the list of instances to which the load balancer sends requests? What type of load balancer are you using — Classic, Application or Network? If it is the Application Load Balancer, then you would have to go to the Target Groups and get the instances from them.

Comment: Hi Jhon Thank you for your reply I am using  classic and I want the  instances where it sends requests

Comment: Also Can you guide me how can I get ec2 instances of application load balancers as well by using target groups

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Classic Load Balancer**

Use: `client = boto3.client('elb')`

Then [`describe_load_balancers()`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elb.html#ElasticLoadBalancing.Client.describe_load_balancers) results include a list of instances:

```
        'Instances': [
            {
                'InstanceId': 'string'
            },
        ],
```

**Application Load Balancer**

Use: `client = boto3.client('elbv2')`

- Call [`describe_target_groups()`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.describe_target_groups) passing in the Load Balancer ARN to obtain a list of **Target Groups** associated with the Load Balancer
- Then call [`describe_target_health()`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.describe_target_health) to obtain a **list of targets** (instances).

Here is a sample response:

```
{
    'TargetHealthDescriptions': [
        {
            'Target': {
                'Id': 'i-0f76fade',
                'Port': 80,
            },
...
```

Comment: Hi Jhon Thank you for your reply is it only fetch status active load balance rs when  I did  describe_load_balancers()

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. Did it give you the information you require? What information are you missing?

Answer (score 2):

for anyone looking for a quick snippet to see if your instance is in the LB:

```
from ec2_metadata import ec2_metadata
instance_id: str = ec2_metadata.instance_id
import boto3
client = boto3.client("elbv2" , region_name="us-west-2")

response = client.describe_target_groups(
        LoadBalancerArn="your arn goes here"
)
target_group_arn = response["TargetGroups"][0]["TargetGroupArn"]

response = client.describe_target_health(TargetGroupArn=target_group_arn)

instances = map(lambda x: x["Target"]["Id"], response["TargetHealthDescriptions"])

print(f"target group instances {list(instances)}")
print(f"this instance {instance_id}")
```