# How to know if an EC2 is registered to some Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I know that in AWS I can check the registered targets of a Load Balancer. If there a way to check if some load balancer has an EC2 among its targets?

Answer (score 2):

**Classic Load Balancer**

Call [describe-load-balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elb/describe-load-balancers.html). Results include a list of instances:

```
        'Instances': [
            {
                'InstanceId': 'string'
            },
        ],
```

**Application Load Balancer**

- Call [describe-load-balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/describe-load-balancers.html) passing in the Load Balancer ARN to obtain a list of **Target Groups** associated with the Load Balancer
- Then call [describe-target-health](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/describe-target-health.html) to obtain a **list of targets** (instances).

Here is a sample response:

```
{
    'TargetHealthDescriptions': [
        {
            'Target': {
                'Id': 'i-0f76fade',
                'Port': 80,
            },
...
```

See also: [aws: boto3 get all instances of a load balancers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51245085/174777)